# Can I say “acquire someone something”?

Tags: verbs, indirect-objects, direct-objects

It’s common to say **“*someone* acquires *something*”**, but is it OK to say **“acquires *someone something*”**?

For example, it is possible to say

> His character acquires him a good name. 
>                       <sup>(where *good name* here means *fame*)</sup>

to mean that he acquires a good name because of his (good) character.

Comment: I've got 1th to say about this: Whether they're standard abbr or no, I've always cringed when I've read _sb/sth_ here.

Comment: When you talk about verbs a lot, which linguists have to do, you find yourself writing things like _make sth_ or _make sb do sth_ in place of _make something_ and _make somebody do something_ as descriptions of verbal constructions. This is not rocket science, and doesn't require calculus - just the desire to learn sth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't find OP's proposed usage particularly "valid" - it just looks like a bad translation to me.

A little stuffy and dated, but I'd go for *"His character **affords** him a good name"*.

> **afford** *- to supply or furnish from its own resources, to yield naturally.* (OED, sense:7)

---

OP mentions *sb acquire sth*, by which I take it he means sentences such as *"John acquired a gun"*.

> **acquire** *- to get by one's own efforts.*  ([thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/acquire), sense:2)

In this context, it's worth noting that we can (just about) say *"The gun afforded John confidence"*, but not *"*The gun acquired John confidence"* - only *"John acquired confidence through the gun"*.